# How to stop an effect from one frame to continue in the next?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have made a program in which small green rectangles (or Greeny here) are periodically generated at the bottom of the screen and inside the movie clip symbol, I have made a classic tween such that it moves to the top of the screen. I have also declared a variable (t) that increments itself periodically (I am running it at 24 fps). When the value variable, t reaches or exceeds 96, it moves to the next frame. The problem however is that even in the next frame, the generation of these small green rectangles do not stop. Please do excuse me if I have asked the question wrongly. By the way the code on frame 2 is just stop();. Here is the code for frame 1-

```
var c:int;
var t:int = 0;
var s:int = 8;
function eFrame(event:Event):void
{
    t++;
    if (t%s == 0)
    {
        var i:Greeny = new Greeny  ;
        i.x = Math.random() * 550;
        i.y = 400;
        stage.addChild(i);
    }
    if (t > 96) {
        nextFrame();
    }
}
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
stop();
```

EDIT - Here is the link for the file - http://www.mediafire.com/download/crjh2fubcbnx3l5/Retro.fla

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove your your event listener on frame 2. Try this (on frame2 or in frame 1 when your condition t>96 is reached):

```
this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
```

Comment: If I add it along with when the condition t>90 is reached, nothing changes. Also the same with typing it on frame 2.

Comment: Ok I found out that every frame, the code repeats itself. So if I give trace("G"); when t == 48, it happens once every time in 4 seconds (4 * 24fps);

Comment: the problem in your code is when t>96, you go to next frame. So depending on the number of frame you have, you go to next until the end, then you return to 1, and the code start again. Try to replace `nextFrame();` with `gotoAndStop(2);`

Comment: Nothing seems to change even when I replace nextFrame(); with gotoAndStop(2);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the generation of green rectangles, you should remove the listener of Event.Enter_Frame, or do something to stop it in function eFrame.

If you want to make all rectangles not visible, you should set theirs "visible" attribute false or remove them from stage .